# Error starting Confluent Control Center with Apple M1

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, apple-m1, confluent-control-center

Control center isn't starting on Apple M1 silicon.  In logs I've found message

```
no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/folders/wz/6d89bfcx4v9dn6wdv2k6vns40000gn/T/librocksdbjni16743350693240187719.jnilib:
 mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I tryed to start it with command "arch -x86_64 confluent local services start" but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you turn on rosetta in the terminal and try again?

Comment: I started with Rosseta, it doesn't work(

Comment: Do you use the docker image for the quick start or the source code? The source code is working well for me, but, I also have the same issue with the docker images. I read that we need to build our own images for the M1 chip but no official doc I find.

Comment: I tried run confluent platform in docker container and I successfully started kafka, but in my project I use kafka streams, and kafka streams didn't work in docker container. I'd drop this idea.

Comment: Can you provide your `docker-compose.yaml` file so I can have a look?